# How to read in a file stored in linux into R?

Tags: r

I have a large file stored in linux. I don't want to transfer the file onto my laptop and then read into R. I was hoping I can read the large file into R without storing the file on my laptop (as my storage is nearly full). The file I want to read into R  Studio is located in my university file path: `/data/genes/h3/PROs_GWAS/output_PROs.bgen`

The file is **not** a txt file but a genotype file e.g. ending is .bgen

I have tried the command below:

```
d = read.table( pipe ('ssh hkj7@spectre2.le.ac.uk "ls /data/genes/h3/PROs_GWAS/output_PROs.bgen"'), header = T )
```

However, this prompts me to a password but then an error which I am assuming is because of the read.table thinking the file is a txt file.

```
Error in read.table(pipe("ssh hkj7@spectre2.le.ac.uk \"ls /data/genes/h3/PROs_GWAS/output_PROs.bgen\""),  : 
  no lines available in input
```

I am not sure how to get round this.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have two options here. You can read this file as a raw binary file which is saved in memory in RStudio.

But assuming you want to read the file, I think this function https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/bigsnpr/html/snp_readBGEN.html might be what you need?

Comment: You might prefer to use the [`ssh`](https://docs.ropensci.org/ssh/) package for `ssh`-based operations.